# HTTP response for "logged in and trying to register"

Tags: rest, api, http, http-status

Say a REST client is logged in and attempts to register, in which case the server ignores the request. What status should be returned here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would return one of the following, as is not a Success request (2xx), redirection (3xx) or Error (5xx):

> 400 (Bad Request)
>
> 400 is the generic client-side error status, **used when no other 4xx
>   error code is appropriate**. Errors can be like malformed request
>   syntax, invalid request message parameters, or deceptive request
>   routing etc.The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without
>   modifications.

or

> 422 Unprocessable Entity
>
> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
>   understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
>   415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
>   syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request)
>   status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
>   instructions.

But is up to you. This assuming that the client sends in the request the Token/Bearer to be logged in and try to do a '*valid*' request to the /*registration* endpoint.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I think I will return 422 because it seems most appropriate.

Comment: Or I can just register new user even when user is logged in. It will not hurt anyone, its just weird